# XBee | Ubuntu (C/C++) | Android

Tags: c++, xbee, android

I am looking for guidance of wireless communication between Ubuntu (code written in C/C++) with an Android device. Since the desired range is about 1 mile (~1.5 km), I assume that XBee Pro would be a proper option. Please kindly provide me some suggestions and examples about C/C++ & Java codes and hardware connection. Thanks.

Comment: This site is for Arduino, not Ubuntu or Android.  I think you might get a better response in the Electrical Engineering forum.  Don't cross post I'll flag it an a mod might move it if they agree.
(Also this question would be shut on here, because its a 'How do I...' type question where you haven't tried to do it and got stuck)

Comment: I suspect that "provide me code" won't get far on EE Stack Exchange, but I agree that this question doesn't seem to be about Arduinos. I'll migrate it.